# Joining Two list using LINQ Query and displaying only relevant data

Tags: c#, linq, console-application

I am new to programming and working on LINQ, I have two list both have different data, the thing I am trying to do is join both of them in a separate list and then display only "Black" and "White" car data using LINQ (Query or IQueryable whatever it is) here is my code, that do entirely different thing

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>();
        cars.Add  (new Cars { Make = "Honda", Model = 2020, Color = "Black"});
        cars.Add  (new Cars { Make = "Suzuki", Model = 2020, Color = "White" });
        cars.Add  (new Cars { Make = "Toyota", Model = 2020, Color = "Green" });
        cars.Add  (new Cars { Make = "Kia", Model = 2020, Color = "Blue" });

        List<MakeBy> makeby = new List<MakeBy>();
        makeby.Add(new MakeBy { Color = "White", Country = "China" });
        makeby.Add(new MakeBy { Color = "Black", Country = "Japan" });
        makeby.Add(new MakeBy { Color = "White", Country = "Japan" });
        makeby.Add(new MakeBy { Color = "White", Country = "Korea" });



        var CombineCars = cars.Zip(makeby, (e, s) => e.Color + "White" + s.Color + "Black");

        foreach(var item in CombineCars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: What kind of results are you expecting in `Console.WriteLine(item);`? Can you provide an example based on your sample data...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following works. If not, please specify more precisely, what output you need.

```
var CombineCars = cars.Join(maekby,
    c => c.Color,
    m => m.Color,
    (c, m) => new
    {
        carMake = c.Make,
        carModel = c.Model,
        carColor = c.Color,
        makeByColor = m.Color,
        makeByCountry = m.Country
    });
```

Now you can access it like:

```
foreach (var car in CombineCars)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Car model: {car.carModel}, car make: {car.carMake}"); //and so on
}
```

Haven't tested it, but it should do what you need.